# Uninitialized Constant in Namespace Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

I haven't had noobie routing errors in a while, but now that I'm using a namespace I don't seem to understand how to trace them...

```
uninitialized constant ShiftedCommerce::BaseItemsController::Item
```

So what exactly is this saying? There's no Item model associated with the BaseItemsController within my namespace?

I don't know why there's a trailing ::item, I don't think it should be there.

Another reason I think something strange is going on is because if I change ANYTHING in the BaseItemController, the page will render once. Then If I reload the page, the same error comes back up. It's extremely frustrating.

Here is my BaseItemControlller

```
class ShiftedCommerce::BaseItemsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_base_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 # GET /items
 # GET /items.json
 def index
   @base_items = BaseItem.all
   @line_item = LineItem.new
   @cart = current_cart
   @title = "Store"
 end

 # GET /items/1
 # GET /items/1.json
 def show
    @cart = current_cart
    @line_item = LineItem.new
 end

 # GET /items/new
 def new
    @base_item = BaseItem.new
 end
```

and my model...

```
class ShiftedCommerce::BaseItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, :through => :items
    has_many :items
    has_many :sizes, :through => :items
    has_many :colors, :through => :items

    before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}
    validates :title, :uniqueness => true
    def one_record_of_variance
        self
    end
    def has_no_variance
    end
    def is_base_item?
        return true if self.class.name == "BaseItem"    
    end
    def is_item?
        return true if self.class.name == "Item"    
    end
    private

      # ensure that there are no line items referencing this product
      def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
        if line_items.empty?
          return true
        else
          errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
          return false
        end
      end
end
```

Here are my paths:

```
App/controllers/shifted_commerce/base_items_controller.rb

App/models/shifted_commerce/models/base_item.rb
```

Comment: Could you post paths to your model and controller? RoR is strict about structuring and naming your files.

Comment: I mean paths like app/controllers/..., app/models/..., what is the path to ShiftedCommerce::BaseItemsController file?

Comment: Well, paths look good. Another thing that could cause this issue is a lack of namespacing for BaseItem and LineItem in controller, - try to write them ShiftedCommerce::BaseItem and ShiftedCommerce::LineItem. Obviously you do not have a model BaseItem ( your have ShiftedCommerce::BaseItem ) and ruby simply tries to find BaseItem within a ShiftedCommerce::BaseItemsController class.

Comment: Isn't that how I have it in my controllers? @tokenvolt

Comment: No, you have BaseItem, should be the whole name including namespace, - ShiftedCommerce::BaseItem.

Comment: ah you mean within the controller? like @base_item = ShiftedCommerce:BaseItem

Comment: yes, but two colons ShiftedCommerce::BaseItem